# Sitecore IDTable primary key

Tags: sql, sitecore

In Sitecore there's a table called IDTable with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IDTable](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
    [Prefix] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CustomData] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It has following indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ndxID] ON [dbo].[IDTable]
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ndxPrefixKey] ON [dbo].[IDTable]
(
    [Prefix] ASC,
    [Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And it is used to map IDs to keys for use with a custom data provider. So this table is being hit near constantly when custom items are being requested and very heavily when indexes are being created etc... One of the most common lookups passing through is based on the ID column.

**My question is: Why would it have been decided that this table requires no primary key? And what would be the pro-contra arguments for adding a primary key?**

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a "why" question that could be difficult to answer. But I'll offer some information that might help you out.

```
<IDTable type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)IDTable, Sitecore.Kernel" singleInstance="true">
  <param connectionStringName="master"/>
  <param desc="cacheSize">500KB</param>
</IDTable>
```

First of all, the IDTable isn't taking the direct hit from the lookups all the time. Sitecore has a caching mechanism around the IDTable, defined in web.config as per above. You can and should increase this cache size if you're dataproviding large quantities of data.

That being said, it probably wouldn't be harmful to add an index to this table. I just don't think you would gain all that much. It depends I guess; how big is the data set you're dataproviding?

Comment: I was fooled by the caching option as well. But IDTable entries are only cached when you lookup key => ID, not when you lookup ID => key. Check Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerIDTable.GetKeys(string, ID).